# Как создать SSH ключ?

Tags: linux, ssh

Выполняю:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

И выдает, мол, уже существует и хочу ли я его перезаписать:

```
/Users/colibri/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
```

Пропускаю, ничего не перезаписываю. Прописываю:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

И в консоли выводит некоторый хэш, где в начале написано:

```
ssh-rsa
```

А в конце:

```
colibri@Colibri-PC.local
```

Это и является ssh ключом?

Comment: Хэш и есть ключ

Comment: `id_rsa` и `id_rsa.pub` и есть уже вполне готовые части SSH-ключа. Закрытая часть `id_rsa` должны знать только вы, никому не показывать и тщательно беречь, а открытую часть `id_rsa.pub` можно раздавать налево и направо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, точнее его *открытой* (расшифровывающей) частью.

Начало (`ssh-rsa`) — это опознавательный признак ключа, а конец (`colibri@Colibri-PC.local`) — произвольные заметки.

*Закрытая* (шифрующая) же часть находится в файле `id_rsa` без расширения.

Comment: Получается, что для авторизации нужна как раз закрытая часть?

Comment: @Colibri, закрытая часть известна только вам. Открытую же часть можно давать любому сервису, который хочет вас авторизовать. Подытоживая: если сайт требует SSH ключ — вводите содержимое pub-файла.